# Remove file when rm its symlink

Tags: linux, symlink, rm

I have storage folder which contains 2 folders - files and tags.

```
files folder structure:

0
1
2
3

etc.
```

Folders 0, 1, 2, 3 contains hashed named files.

```
tags folder structure:

private
public
admin
```

Folders private, public, admin contains symlinks from folder files that can be stored in files/0, files/1 etc.

I want to delete all files with tag admin. When I removing symlinks in admin folder its not deleting from files folder. It's possible to remove symlink and it's file?

1 file in files folder = 1 symlink in tags folder.

Comment: In this case, `rm /folder[12]/1.txt` would remove both the file and the link. I wondering whether there's something more to this question than that though.

Comment: Are you looking for an "enhanced" `rm` that would go looking (in some places?) for symlinks to a file?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes. I know my symlink paths but missing oryginal file path and I need to delete those files.

Comment: So you want something that finds all symbolic links, removes whatever they point to (assuming they point to files somewhere under some top-level directory, I presume, not _any_ file), and then removes the symbolic links themselves?